# Windows DockerFile COPY folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I Have following structure in my project

[image]

I'm trying to run
following in cmd
docker build -t counter-bal-image  '.\docker.'

My docker file has following line
COPY cicd/scripts/* /App/scripts/

When i run i get COPY failed: no source files were specified

How to copy relative folders?

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

If you build in `./docker` then that's where everything must live. Instead specify the path to the `Dockerfile` but build in the current directory:

```
docker build -f docker/Dockerfile -t counter-bal-image .
```

Since you're building in `.` then `./cicd` becomes accessible.